How to read a value from JSON using Ansible?
Have the below Sample JSON:
{
"fulfilmentOrderItems": [
    {
        "customerDates": {
        },
        "instanceCharacteristics": [
            {
                "name": "VLAN",
                "value": "24",
                "action": "Cancel"
            }
        ],
        "orderLineId": {
            "value": "123456-10",
            "source": "AS"
        }
    }
    ],
    "orderId": {
        "identifier": {
            "value": "1234567-96_11",
            "source": "AS"
        },
        "version": 1
    }
}

How do I extract a certain value like the name i.e VLAN or the value (12321321412a-10)?
Tried using
- name: Read data from Json
  set_fact:
    Value: "{{ lookup('file', 'POST.json') | from_json }}"

- name: Get the value from JSON
  debug:
    msg: "The value is  {{ value.value }}"

I get the below output
TASK [Get the value from JSON] ************************
fatal:FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'value' is undefined


instanceCharacteristics is a list. To get the first item attribute value you need fulfilmentOrderItems.0.instanceCharacteristics.0.value.

thank you very much , i am now able to read the value from the json. How do we replace the value i.e 24 . I need to update the value and pass the json.

Q: "How do we replace the value i.e 24? I need to update the value and pass the JSON."
It is not possible to update variables in places, however, you could use update_fact module – Update currently set facts to create an other data structure.
A minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: sample.json
        name: readFromFile

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ readFromFile }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ((readFromFile.fulfilmentOrderItems | first).instanceCharacteristics | first).value }}"

    - name: Update the fact
      ansible.utils.update_fact:
        updates:
          - path: readFromFile.fulfilmentOrderItems[0].instanceCharacteristics[0].value
            value: '0'
      register: updated

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ updated.readFromFile }}"

will result into an output of
TASK [include_vars] ***********
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    fulfilmentOrderItems:
    - customerDates: {}
      instanceCharacteristics:
      - action: Cancel
        name: VLAN
        value: '24'
      orderLineId:
        source: AS
        value: 123456-10
    orderId:
      identifier:
        source: AS
        value: 1234567-96_11
      version: 1

TASK [debug] *****************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '24'

TASK [Update the fact] *******
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    fulfilmentOrderItems:
    - customerDates: {}
      instanceCharacteristics:
      - action: Cancel
        name: VLAN
        value: '0'
      orderLineId:
        source: AS
        value: 123456-10
    orderId:
      identifier:
        source: AS
        value: 1234567-96_11
      version: 1

Further Readings

How to read JSON file using Ansible?
Ansible - Alter Registered Variable
How slicing in Python works

